# Is it possible to convert any arbitrary file to a string? (C#)

Tags: c#, json

I need to store an arbitrary amount of files (with any file type) as a property on a class. This class will get serialized to a JSON file. Later the user can load the JSON file back into the app, and has the ability to recreate the files they originally loaded. Right now I'm storing the files as an array of bytes. The issue is that some of the files are large, and the array of bytes is too large and is causing the serialization/deserializationto take a very long time.

Is there a way I can store the files as a string/array of strings instead of bytes? Or some different way of storing the files? What are some options to deal with this problem?

**edit**:
I believe a string would be faster because right now when the byte array is being rendered out in JSON in ascii format, so it looks like this:
150,123,43,62...

Comment: Why do you believe that a string would be smaller than a byte array? Or rather, what would this string have?

Comment: A string would be at least twice as big as the array of bytes, depending on the encoding used.

Comment: Large files will take a long time to load, not much you can do in software to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode your byte array as a base 64 string using [`Convert.ToBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That should reduce the size of your JSON significantly:  http://rextester.com/ILJNV57711

For example, here's a random byte array, serialized as JSON:

```
[95,103,154,174,23,5,178,179,158,186,181,89,40,229,233,168,217,42,98,65,248]
```

Here's the same array, converted to a base 64 string, serialized as JSON:

```
"X2earhcFsrOeurVZKOXpqNkqYkH4"
```

It's plain to see that a byte array is smaller in JSON when expressed as a base 64 string.  It goes from 76 characters to 30.

Comment: I tried this:
var horribleWay = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath); var goodWay = Convert.ToBase64String(horribleWay);

I tested this on a small file, and when I looked at the count for each, I found horribleWay = 10152, and goodWay = 13536. What's going on?

Comment: @user3715648 your file is 10kb, but the data you're writing to json is an array of 10,000 numbers. The base64 should be written out as a string.

Comment: Ahh yes. Silly me. One last thing: How would I write this string back to a file? Do i need to convert it back to an array of bytes?

Comment: Use [`Convert.FromBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly don't store the byte array as decimal numbers like that; Base64 encode it at the very least. Base64 encoding will enlarge the data to 133% of the raw file size but that'll be a massive improvement from the 400% enlargement you're currently using.

Comment: So something like this?:
var horribleWay = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var goodWay = Convert.ToBase64String(horribleWay);

Comment: When I tried this the size of horribleWay was smaller than goodWay. Why would this happen?